# Threads cause GUI to freeze up

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

So I'm not the most experienced with the C# programming language, however I've been making a few test applications here and there.

I've noticed that the more threads I create for an application I'm working on, the more my GUI starts to freeze. I'm not sure why this occurs, I previously thought that part of the point of multi-threading an application was to avoid the GUI from freezing up.

An explanation would be appreciated.

Also, here's the code I use to create the threads:

```
private void runThreads(int amount, ThreadStart address)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        threadAmount += 1;
        Thread currentThread = new Thread(address);
        currentThread.Start();
    }
}
```

and here's what the threads run:

```
private void checkProxies()
{
    while (started)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.co.nz/");
            request.Timeout = (int)timeoutCounter.Value * 1000;
            request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxies[proxyIndex]);
            Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("currentProxy"), proxies[proxyIndex]);
            if (proxyIndex != proxies.Length)
            {
                proxyIndex += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                started = false;
            }
            request.GetResponse();
            workingProxies += 1;
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            deadProxies += 1;
        }

        lock ("threadAmount")
        {
            if (threadAmount > proxies.Length - proxyIndex)
            {
                threadAmount -= 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question - which version of .NET are you using? If you're using 4 (or later) you can make use of the `Task` class. 4.5 also has the `async` and `await` keywords available. Finally, if the only reason you're using threads is to run different `WebRequest`, then said class also has a `BeginGetResponse` and `EndGetResponse` methods allowing you to run them in the background.

Comment: What is the value passed in as `amount`? How many threads are you spinning?

Comment: To expand on why @YuvalItzchakov is asking for the value of `amount` - if you start a high number of threads then the GUI will suffer simply because you're overloading the system.

Comment: I'm current using .NET 4.5 for my application. The reason why I'm using multiple threads is to make the process a lot faster. So the task class is an alternative to threads? Will that help resolve the GUI freezing issues? Also,  I have very little experience with C# so, to be honest, I'm not sure how I would utilize those methods. **Edit:** Currently my GUI starts lagging at about ~100 threads. However, the reason why I am confused is that I've ran different applications (not written by myself and they were coded in Java) with around ~256 threads and have had no issues with the GUI freezing.

Comment: wait wait... you dont expect your cpu can handle any amount of threads?

Comment: Start the application, let it run until it freezes, click the 'pause' button in visual studio. Find the Main Thread in the "Debug Location" toolbar and see what the UI/Main thread is doing.

Comment: Not at all, @M.kazemAkhgary, but as I said I've ran more threads in other applications and had to issues with the GUI freezing at all.

Comment: @Erno de Weerd, I will try that and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Using a BackGroundWorker is one method to solve issue.  Other solutions will also work.

Comment: Are you trying to write an attack on http://google.co.nz?

Comment: ["You should not force a tag into your title. (...) The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Absolutely not, @Jodrell. The reason why I'm using the Google website in my code is simply because of the fact that the Google website is virtually never down.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @BCdotWEB. I have not added any tags to my title? **Edit:** Actually, you may be correct. I guess a moderator removed it (it shows that they edited my post). Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I cannot tell you why exactly your code is slowing the GUI down, there are a few things in your code you should do to make it all-round better. If the problem persist then, then it should be a lot easier to pinpoint the issue.

1. Creating `Thread` objects is expensive. This is why new classes were added in C# to better handle multi-threading. Now you have access to the `Task` class or the `Parallel` class (described below).
2. Judging from the comments, you're running a LOT of threads at the same time. While it shouldn't be an issue to *just* run them, you're not really getting much use out of them if what you're doing is firing `WebRequests` (unless you have an awesome network). Use multiple threads, sure, but limit their number.
3. A `Task` is great when you want to do a specific operation in the background. But when you want to repeat a single operation for a specific set of data in the background... why not use the `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel` class? Specifically, `Parallel.ForEach` (where you can specify your list of proxies as the parameter). This method also lets you set up how many threads are supposed to run concurrently at any given moment by using `ParallelOptions`.
4. One more way to code would be to make use of the `async` and `await` keywords available in .NET 4.5. In this case your GUI (button press?) should invoke an `async` method.
5. Use thread-safe methods like `Interlocked.Increment` or `Interlocked.Add` to increase / decrease counters available from multiple threads. Also, consider that you could change your list of proxies to a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>` (where `bool` indicates if the proxy works or not) and set the values without any worry as each thread will only access its own entry in the dictionary. You can easily queue the totals at the end using LINQ: `dictionary.Where(q => q.Value).Count()` to get the number of working proxies, for example. Of course other classes are also available, depending on how you want to tackle the issue - perhaps a `Queue` (or `ConcurrentQueue`)?
6. Your `lock` shouldn't really work... as in, it seems it's working by accident than by design in your code (thanks Luaan for the comment). But you really shouldn't do that. Consult the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.120%29.aspx) on `lock` to get a better understanding of how it works. The `Object` created in the MSDN example isn't just for show.
7. You can also make the requests themselves multi-threaded by using `BeginGetResponse` and `EndGetResponse` methods. You can, in fact, combine this with the `Task` class for a much cleaner code (the `Task` class can convert Begin/End method pairs into a single `Task` object).

So, a quick recap - use the `Parallel` class for multi-threading, and use concurrency classes for keeping things in place.

Here's a quick example I wrote:

```
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool?> values = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool?>();

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await CheckProxies();
        label.Content = result.ToString();
    }

    async Task<int> CheckProxies()
    {
        //I don't actually HAVE a list of proxies, so I make up some data
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            values[Guid.NewGuid().ToString()] = null;
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach(values, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, this.PeformOperation));
        //note that with maxDegreeOfParallelism set to a high value (like 1000)
        //then I'll get a TON of failed requests simply because I'm overloading the network
        //either that or google thinks I'm DDOSing them... >_<
        return values.Where(v => v.Value == true).Count();
    }

    void PeformOperation(KeyValuePair<string, bool?> kvp)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.co.nz/");
            request.Timeout = 100;
            //I'm not actually setting up the proxy from kvp,
            //because it's populated with bogus data
            request.GetResponse();

            values[kvp.Key] = true;
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            values[kvp.Key] = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sadly, I'm affraid the `lock` actually *will* work - the string constant is going to be interned, so it does always point to the same instance. It's still a horrible idea, though - it's like having a synchronization object that's `public readonly static`.

Comment: Very nice approach, first cleaning up all the obvious threading issues before trying to suss the actual problem - if it will even remain. Btw if you're already there, consider going with the naturally async HttpClient to improve parallelism...

Answer (score 3):

Despite the other comments being correct in that you should use either the `Task` class, or better yet, the `async` API, that is not the reason you're locking up.

The line of code that is causing your threads to lock up is this:

```
request.Timeout = (int)timeoutCounter.Value * 1000;
```

I am assuming that `timeoutCounter` is a control on the WinForm - *which is running on the main GUI thread*.
In other words, your threads' code is trying to access a control which is not in it's own thread, which is not really "allowed", at least not so simply.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661561/10080) shows how to do this, albeit most of the answers there are a bit dated.

From a quick google (okay who am I kidding, I binged it) I found [this article](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/246911-c%23-multi-threading-in-a-gui-environment/) that explains the problem rather well.

Comment: I've tried (and I just retried) setting that to a static value (5000), however the issue still occurs. **Edit:** By the way, you were correct by assuming that ``timeoutCounter`` is a control (it's a ``NumericUpDown`` control).

Comment: @PotatoGun Is there nowhere else you are referencing a control on the main GUI thread? E.g. is the `proxies` variable (string array?) defined on the Form's thread?

Comment: Wait, I might be wrong - something else to look at, could this line `Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("currentProxy"), proxies[proxyIndex]);` be the cause of the incremental freezing? MSDN states "For better performance, use fields that are marked with the ThreadStaticAttribute attribute instead." Using `.SetData()` accesses the TLS indirectly (not to mention boxing) - I'm curious if this could cause substantial overhead with many threads?

Comment: The variable is defined outside the method that the threads have access to, so that actually might be the issue. However, the reason for that is because I'm using that in multiple methods (checking and loading the proxies initially), and I'm not exactly sure if there's a workaround for that.

Other variables, such as the proxyIndex variable, are stored outside of any methods, simply because of the fact that I don't want them to be re-defined with the value of 0 every time the method is entered. **Edit:**  Just noticed your new message, I'll look into it in a second. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think getting `timeoutCounter` could be the issue. C# throws an error when attempting to access GUI-controlled data from outside the GUI thread.